# Mojolicious database plugin - helper error

Tags: mysql, mojolicious-lite

I am trying to use [Mojolicious database plugin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious-Plugin-Database/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Database.pm), and find some difficulties. My first two pages of Google results about this topics are already visited.
Scenario is very simple: connect to a db (mysql), fetch some data, display it.
Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojolicious::Plugin::Database;

# [...]

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->plugin('database', {
            dsn      => 'dbi:MySQL:dbname=y',
            username => $mysql_user,
            password => $mysql_passwd,
            helper   => 'ydb',
            });
};

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $zz=$c->ydb->prepare("select count(*) from customers");
    my $total=$zz->execute();                                 
    $c->ydb->bind_columns(\$total);
    $c->ydb->fetch;
    $c->session(customer=>$total);
    $c->render(template => 'index');
};
```

but I received the error:

> Can't locate object method "ydb" via package "Mojolicious::Controller"

I am surely missing some basics. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's potentially not the best module choice.  Mojo::mysql is actively maintained, supports non-blocking database queries, and manages a pool of database handles to allow queries to run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll go that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got the helper from the plugin working. I created my own helper in combination with Mojo::mysql.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::mysql;

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
}

helper ydb => sub {
        my $c = shift ;
        return Mojo::mysql->strict_mode('mysql://muziek:muziek@localhost/muziek') 
};

get '/foo' => sub {
  my $c = shift ;

  my $db = $c->ydb->db;
  my $row = $db->query("select count(*) COUNT from TITLE")->hash;
  $c->render(text => "Hello from /foo. count="  . $row->{COUNT} );
};

app->start;
```